# mobx @inject not creating new (decorated) component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I'm trying to setup a React application using mobx for state management.

I've defined a store like so:

> ApplicationStore.js

```
import { observable, action, reaction } from 'mobx';

class ApplicationStore {

  @observable appName = 'App';
  @observable currentRoute = '/';
  @observable appLoaded = false;

  @action setAppLoaded() {
      this.appLoaded = true;
  }
}

export default new ApplicationStore();
```

Using it in `Root.js` to collect stores/debug tools and passing it to main App component:

> Root.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { Provider } from 'mobx-react';

import App from './App.js';

import './Root.css';

import ApplicationStore from './stores/ApplicationStore';

const stores = { ApplicationStore }

class Root extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider {...stores}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default Root;
```

> App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Login from './views/login/Login'
import Dashboard from './views/dashboard/Dashboard'

import { observer, inject } from 'mobx-react';

import { Switch, Route, BrowserRouter, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

@inject('ApplicationStore')
@observer
class App extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.props)
    };

   render() {

    var loggedIn = false;        

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" render={() => (
              loggedIn ? (
                <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
              ) : (
                <Redirect to="/login" />
              )
              )} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The `console.log(this.props)` in `componentDidMount()` shows that there are empty props.

Not only that, inspecting `<Provider>`'s children in React-dev-tools shows that `@inject` isn't creating a new component (it shows `<App>` instead of the expected `<inject-App-with-ApplicationStore>`.

I don't understaaaaaaaaand

Comment: Since your code looks correct, I make just a wild guess: try replacing `<Provider {...stores}>` with `<Provider applicationStore={ApplicationStore}>` and then `@inject('applicationStore')` (notice small-case reference)

Comment: Figured out the answer. Currently responding to question. Was an issue with my babel config.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with the babel config. I'm using the `react-app-rewired` approach to adding decorator functionality to `create-react-app` [which can be seen here...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v3sJUzFXhz4)

In the `config-overrides.js` file I had:

```
const { injectBabelPlugin } = require("react-app-rewired");

module.exports = function override(config, env) {

    config = injectBabelPlugin(['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', {decoratorsBeforeExport: false}], config);

    return config;
}
```

I changed it to:

```
...
     config = injectBabelPlugin(['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', {"legacy": true}], config);
...
```

and it's now working as intended.

Comment: Dude, thank you for this! I've been struggling for the past 2 hours to understand why a perfectly good implementation (as per their examples and other online models) was not working with `@inject`, even though it was working with `inject(...)`. Hope this helps another poor soul someday. :)

Comment: @AlexFlorin No problem glad it could help! :)